# Problem with buttons showing on top layer with jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-button, android-jetpack

I'm trying to convert my old XML layout to @Composable classes in a test app I made, but I encountered a problem with my "loading" screen.

The app has a button to fetch quotes from a free API and, when clicked, a loading screen should appear on top of the page, effectively blocking possible further interactions with the button.
The loading screen was previously RelativeLayout with a ProgressBar inside.

Now with Compose I cannot manage to have this loading screen to be "on top" because the buttons still show above it and remain clickable.

[image: Wrong effect with buttons showing on top of loading]

The same "wrong" behaviour can also be reproduced with XML layouts when using MaterialButtons, whereas with AppCompatButtons the issue is solved.

Is there a way to make this work in compose?

p.s. here is my solution with Compose

```
@Composable
fun QuoteButton(text: String, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Button(
        onClick,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(20.dp),
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(horizontal = 20.dp, vertical = 5.dp)
    ) {
        Text(text = text)
    }
}

@Composable
fun QuoteLoading(
    isLoading: MutableState<Boolean>,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) = if (isLoading.value) {
    Box(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.3f))
            .pointerInput(Unit) {}
    ) {
        CircularProgressIndicator(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center))
    }
    content()
} else {
    content()
}

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ComposeTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    QuoteLoading(isLoading = loadingState) {
                        Column {
                            QuoteDisplay(textState)
                            QuoteButton(getString(R.string.button_fetch_quote)) {
                                viewModel.setEvent(Event.GetQuote)
                            }
                            QuoteButton(getString(R.string.button_save_quote)) {
                                viewModel.setEvent(Event.SaveQuote)
                            }
                            QuoteButton(getString(R.string.button_clear_quotes)) {
                                viewModel.setEvent(Event.ClearQuote)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

private val DarkColorPalette = darkColors(
    primary = Color(0xFFBB86FC),
    primaryVariant = Color(0xFF3700B3),
    secondary = Color(0xFF03DAC5)
)

private val LightColorPalette = lightColors(
    primary = Color(0xFF6200EE),
    primaryVariant = Color(0xFF3700B3),
    secondary = Color(0xFF03DAC5)
)

@Composable
fun ComposeTheme(darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(), content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    MaterialTheme(
        colors = if (darkTheme) DarkColorPalette else LightColorPalette,
        content = content
    )
}
```

Comment: Your box is placed underneath the content, that's why it doesn't block the pointer. You just need to swap the views order. Also it's a bad practice to build wrappers as you do in `QuoteLoading`, because `content` is gonna be re-created. To make it reused you have to use the same view in both cases, not creating a new view in each `if` case, like [this](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/a272c50c04b2fe097e9d87be9f322c8b)

Comment: I think you can delete this question as it's gonna be impossible for anyone with the same problem to reach it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer Philip, I'm new to Compose and there is still much to learn. Incidentally, does your Gist solve both the "remarks" (I mean order placement AND wrapper) or only the ordering? How to address the bad practice of wrappers?

Comment: Yes, it solves both. If you have any parameters annotated with `@Composable` such as `content` it should only be called once.

Answer (score 0):

First of all put your progress bar in a dialogue that is not cancellable by any input except loading has been finished.

```
@Composable
fun QuoteLoading(
    isLoading: MutableState<Boolean>,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) = if (isLoading.value) {
    Box(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.3f))
            .pointerInput(Unit) {}
    ) {
        Dialog(
           onDismissRequest = onDismiss,
           properties = DialogProperties(dismissOnBackPress = false, 
                           dismissOnClickOutside = false),
           content = {
               CircularProgressIndicator()
           }
       )
    }
    content()
} else {
    content()
}
```